# Chebyshev polynomials to hypergeometric function?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function, chebyshev-polynomials

I am trying to derive this hypergeometric version of the Chebyshev polynomials

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_expressions

$$U_n(x)  = \frac{\left (x+\sqrt{x^2-1} \right )^{n+1} - \left (x-\sqrt{x^2-1} \right )^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{x^2-1}} $$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor} \binom{n+1}{2k+1} \left (x^2-1 \right )^k x^{n-2k} $$

$$ = x^n \sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor} \binom{n+1}{2k+1} \left (1 - x^{-2} \right )^k $$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor} \binom{2k-(n+1)}{k}~(2x)^{n-2k}  \text{ for }~ n > 0$$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor} (-1)^k \binom{n-k}{k}~(2x)^{n-2k}  \text{ for }~ n > 0 $$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-2)^{k} \frac{(n+k+1)!} {(n-k)!(2k+1)!}(1 - x)^k  \text{ for }~ n > 0$$

$$ = (n+1) \ {}_2F_1\left(-n,n+2; \tfrac{3}{2}; \tfrac{1}{2}(1-x)  \right) $$

How do you go from the floor function summation part to the hypergeometric part? Which binomial identities are used? How do you go from $(2x)^{n-2k}$ to $(1-x)^{k}$?

Comment: The Wikipedia page doesn't have a deduction of a formula, but a list of equalities. Each equality is not a consequence of the previous one, it's just enumerating different expressions for the Chebyshev polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We show the following identity is valid for $n\geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor} (-1)^k \binom{n-k}{k}~(2x)^{n-2k} 
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-2)^{k}\binom{n+k+1}{2k+1}(1 - x)^k }\tag{1}
\end{align*}

The bivariate generating function of the *[Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html)*  is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{u(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-2xy+y^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}U_n(x)y^n}
\end{align*}
In the following we consider the generating function $\pi(x,y)$
\begin{align*}
\pi(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-(2+x)y+y^2}=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2-xy}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
which is related with $u(x,y)$ by a transformation $x\to 2x-2$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\pi(2x-2,y)=u(x,y)}
\end{align*}

> Expanding the left-hand expression of $\pi(x,y)$ we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\pi(x,y)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-(2+x)y+y^2}}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left((2+x)y-y^2\right)^n\tag{3.1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(2+x)^k(-1)^{n-k}y^{n-k}\right)y^n\tag{3.2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(2+x)^{n-k}(-1)^ky^{n+k}\tag{3.3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}(2+x)^{n-k}(-1)^ky^{n+k}\tag{3.4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=2k}^{\infty}\binom{n-k}{k}(2+x)^{n-2k}(-1)^ky^n\tag{3.5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}
> \binom{n-k}{k}(2+x)^{n-2k}(-1)^k\right)y^n}\tag{3.6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3.1) we use a *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Infinite_series)*.
- In (3.2) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (3.3) we change the order of the inner sum $k\to n-k$.
- In (3.4) we exchange the order of the sums.
- In (3.5) we shift the index $n$ by $k$ to change $y^{n-k}\to y^n$.
- In (3.6) we shift again the order of the sums.

> Expanding the right-hand expression of $\pi(x,y)$ we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\pi(x,y)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2-xy}}
> =\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}\,\frac{1}{1-\frac{xy}{(1-y)^2}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(xy)^n}{(1-y)^{2n}}\tag{4.1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2n-2}{k}(-y)^k(xy)^n\tag{4.2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n+k+1}{k}x^ny^{n+k}\tag{4.3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{2n-k+1}{k}x^{n-k}y^n\tag{4.4}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n-k+1}{k}x^{n-k}y^n\tag{4.5}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k+1}{n-k}x^k\right)y^n\tag{4.6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k+1}{2k+1}x^k\right)y^n}\tag{4.7}\\
> \end{align*}
> It follows from (3.6) and (4.6) by comparing the coefficients of $y^n$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}
> \binom{n-k}{k}(2+x)^{n-2k}(-1)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k+1}{2k+1}x^k}
> \end{align*}
> Replacing $x$ by $2x-2$ and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (4.1) we use a geometric series expansion.
- In (4.2) we use a *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (4.3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (4.4) we exchange the order of the sums and we shift the index $n$ by $k$ to change $y^{n-k}\to y^n$.
- In (4.5) we exchange the order of the sums.
- In (4.6) we change the order of the inner sum $k\to n-k$.
- In (4.7) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.

**Note:** This answer is a solution to chapter 2, problem 18.c in *[Combinatorial Identities](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-78/issue-4/Review-John-Riordan-Combinatorial-identities/bams/1183533877.full)* by John Riordan.

Comment: I have added an answer using Egorychev method. (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate proof of the identity by @epi163sqrt. We seek

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(-1)^k {n-k\choose k} (2x)^{n-2k}
= \sum_{k=0}^n (-2)^k {n+k+1\choose 2k+1} (1-x)^k.$$

We get for the coefficient on $[x^q]$ of the RHS where
$0\le q\le n:$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-2)^k {n+k+1\choose 2k+1}
(-1)^q {k \choose q}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^n (-2)^k {n+k+1\choose n-k}
(-1)^q {k\choose q}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n (-2)^k z^k (1+z)^k
(-1)^q {k\choose q}.$$

Here may extend to infinity because of the coefficient extractor:

$$(-1)^q [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} \sum_{k\ge 0} (-2)^k z^k (1+z)^k
{k\choose q}
\\ = (-1)^q [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} \sum_{k\ge q} (-2)^k z^k (1+z)^k
{k\choose q}
\\ = (-1)^q [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1}
(-2)^q z^q (1+z)^q
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-2)^k z^k (1+z)^k
{k+q\choose q}
\\ = (-1)^q [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1}
(-2)^q z^q (1+z)^q
\frac{1}{(1+2z(1+z))^{q+1}}
\\ = 2^q [z^{n-q}] (1+z)^{n+q+1}
\frac{1}{(1+2z+2z^2)^{q+1}}.$$

This is

$$2^q \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^{n-q+1}} (1+z)^{n+q+1} \frac{1}{(1+2z+2z^2)^{q+1}}.$$

Now put $z/(1+z)=w$ so that $z=w/(1-w)$ and $dz = 1/(1-w)^2 \; dw$ to
get

$$2^q \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n-q+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2q}}
\frac{1}{(1+2w/(1-w)+2w^2/(1-w)^2)^{q+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
\\ = 2^q \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n-q+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2q}}
\frac{(1-w)^{2q+2}}{((1-w)^2+2w(1-w)+2w^2)^{q+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
\\ = 2^q \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n-q+1}}
\frac{1}{(1+w^2)^{q+1}}
= 2^q [w^{n-q}] \frac{1}{(1+w^2)^{q+1}}.$$

Here we see that $n$ and $q$ must have the same parity, i.e. $n-q=2k$
where $0\le k\le \lfloor n/2 \rfloor.$ Letting $q=n-2k$ we find

$$2^{n-2k} [w^{2k}] \frac{1}{(1+w^2)^{n-2k+1}}
= 2^{n-2k} [w^k] \frac{1}{(1+w)^{n-2k+1}}
\\ = 2^{n-2k} (-1)^k {n-2k+k\choose n-2k}
= 2^{n-2k} (-1)^k {n-k\choose n-2k}
= 2^{n-2k} (-1)^k {n-k\choose k}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: Great derivation! (+1)